# Average value between each element of the array

Tags: javascript

I need help with my React Native app. I need to calculate the average value between each element of the array. The logic is as follows, if there are 4 elements with values 3,5,6,9, then you need to calculate the average value between 3 and 5 and divide by 1, between 3, 5, 6 and divide by 2, etc. The first value is counted as the initial value, so it is not taken into account.

I would appreciate any help.

```
    return (
        <View style={Styles.sectionContainer}>
            {readings.map(
                ({
                    id,
                    date,
                    volume,
                }) => {
                    return (
                        <View key={id} style={Styles.card}>
                            <Text
                                style={[
                                    Styles.sectionHeading,
                                    Styles.darkAppText,
                                    { fontWeight: "bold" },
                                ]}
                            >
                                average: {average}
                            </Text>
                        </View>
                    );
                }
            )}
        </View>
    );
}
```

I was trying to do this inside map function, but it gives average between 2 last elements:

```
if (id == 1) {
  average = 0;
} else if (id > 1) {
  for (i = 1; i < readings.length; i++) {
    average = (readings[i].volume readings[i - 1].volume) / i;
  }
}
```

Comment: Your problem description seems unrelated to reactjs. Please reduce the code to *just* the problem of generating these averages based on an input array. Surely the presence of a UI framework is irrelevant for the problem. Side note: it is bad practice to mix logic with UI: separate them (see [separation of concerns](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_concerns)). Also: you have not explained what the current problem is with your implementation.

Comment: You want the average difference between the initial value and all subsequent values as I understand it

Comment: *"but it doesn't work"*: this is not a very useful problem description. Please provide an example of input for which you get the wrong result and what would have been the expected output. Add the code to initialise this input so we can reproduce the issue. Again, remove aspects of reactjs and sqlite as they are not essential to your question.

Comment: Please also include the input variable, and the expected outcome

Comment: Why is there an `if (id == 1)`? Is that related to your problem? Why are there `<View>` tags in your question? Is there a problem related to tags? Please reduce your question to the essence only.

Comment: *"The first value is counted as the initial value, so it is not taken into account."*: your code does not seem to omit the first value, as you just `.map()` **all** entries (also the first). So what is the output you expect for the first entry?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although you write that the first value is not to be taken into account, you seem to still want to output something for it. Maybe that is the role of the `if (id == 0)` statement, although there is no (explained) reason why the entry with `id` 0 should be the *first* one. Yet you seem to want to map that first entry to 0.

You can use this function for that:

```js
function runningVolumeAverage(arr) {
    let sum = 0;
    return arr.map(({volume}, i) => {
        sum += volume;
        return i && sum / i;
    });
}

const readings = [{ volume: 3 }, { volume: 5 }, { volume: 6 }, { volume: 9 }];
console.log(runningVolumeAverage(readings));
```

If you want to exclude that zero, and want to have one fewer value in your output than you have in your input, then apply `.slice(1)` to the returned array:

```
console.log(runningVolumeAverage(readings).slice(1));
```

In your actual code you could integrate it as follows (assuming all the rest of your code is fine, and only the `average` was the missing piece of info):

```
const averages = runningVolumeAverage(readings);
return (
        <View style={Styles.sectionContainer}>
            {readings.map(
                ({
                    id,
                    date,
                    volume,
                }, i) => {  // <-- get the index
                    return (
                        <View key={id} style={Styles.card}>
                            <Text
                                style={[
                                    Styles.sectionHeading,
                                    Styles.darkAppText,
                                    { fontWeight: "bold" },
                                ]}
                            >
                                average: {averages[i]} // <-- get the average
                            </Text>
                        </View>
                    );
                }
            )}
        </View>
    );
```

Comment: Thank you, this code is working, but I don't know how to do this inside my readings.map function

Comment: Added a section to my answer.

Answer (score 0):

The below functions compute the average values according to what you've described and returns them as an `Array`:

```js
const data = [3,5,6,9];

function avg(first, ...rest) {
  const v = rest.reduce((a, b) => a + b, first);
  return v / rest.length;
}

function getAvgAll(values) {
  const results = [];
  for (let i = 1; i < values.length; i += 1) {
    results.push(avg(...values.slice(0, i + 1)));
  }
  return results;
}

console.log(getAvgAll(data));
```

Answer (score 0):

EDIT :Your problem has nothing to do with React Native rather its simply a JS job.here is the code

```
function calculateAverageValues(arr) {
  if (arr.length < 2) {
    return []; // If there are less than 2 items,return empty
  }

  const outputArray = [];
  let sum = arr[0]; // Initialize the sum with the first item 

  for (let i = 1; i < arr.length; i++) {
    sum += arr[i]; // Add the current element to the sum.
    const average = sum / i; // Calculate the average value.
    outputArray.push(average); // Push the average value to output 
 
  }

  return outputArray;
}
```

Example usage:

```
const inputArray = [3, 5, 6, 9];
const result = calculateAverageValues(inputArray);
console.log(result); // Output:[ 8, 7, 7.666666666666667 ]
```

Comment: @David I wouldn't be so sure about that until the OP shows us an expected output.

Comment: @Behemoth I would say the OP has been pretty clear: "calculate the average value between 3 and 5 and divide by 1, between 3, 5, 6 and divide by 2, etc." - `(3 + 5) / 1` results in `8`, not in `4`.

Comment: Read that sentence once more ;) *Calculate the average value between 3 and 5* -> Makes 4. *and divide by 1* -> We still got 4. To me, this is everything but clear.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want to calculate the averages of your array following such a pattern:

*pseudo code*:

```
[
   average(array[0]...array[1]),
   average(array[0]...array[2]),
   average(array[0]...array[3]),
   ...
   average(array[0]...array[array.length - 1])
]
```

You could do something like this:

```js
const values = [3, 5, 6, 9];

const averages = values.flatMap((el, i, array) => {
  const length = i + 2;
  if (length > array.length) return [];
  const part = array.slice(0, length);
  return part.reduce((a, b) => a + b) / part.length;
});

console.log(averages);
```

Answer (score 0):

For the first element and the last element in the array I choose to return a value of 0 you could change it for whatever value you want.

```
const array = [3,5,6,9]
const arrayValuePerIndex = array.map((item, index, origArray) => {
    return index === 0 ? 0 : index< origArray.length - 1? (item + origArray[index + 1]) / (index + 1) : 0; 
});

console.log(arrayValuePerIndex) // [ 0, 5.5, 5, 0 ]
```